# Disable close app when press home button and recent android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my app, when user press recent button my app disable close but when user press home button my app will close

```
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);
    }
```

And permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
```

I try with onUserLeaveHint only Android 12 work

Comment: By pressing both buttons, method `onPause()` is called, what is your problem exactly?

Comment: my problem when user press recent button my app cannot close but user press home button my app can close. I want my app stay in app.

Comment: You can't do this, the home button is controlled by the system.

Comment: How to disable close app if i can't controll home button?

Comment: Use custom android or a warning when the user exits